# inkscape document properties

Tags: inkscape

Every time I open [document properties] the dialogue window opens far left or right and I have to drag it into view. Is there a setting so when I open the dialogue it will open in the center of the screen and not some random place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can drag'n'drop the window to be a dock:

[image: Document properties docked on the right side]

Note that after this action, your dock will have the minimum width of that property page.

In order to drag'n'drop properly, grab it like this:

[image: How to drag]

Comment: that works so much better. I may make a video how to of it and post it. Thanks a bunch.